# Extending Entity Framework Models for SAAS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building an asp.net mvc application that is using Entity Framework 6. We have the challenge of building several implementations of this same application. So we have created a core library called `MyApp.Core` which contains the following:

- DbContext
- Models

  - Customer
  - Product
  - (other models)
- Repositories

We have the need to extend models for different implementations of the application. For example we might want to put `SomeProperty` on the customer table for 1 customer and `SomeOtherProperty` for another customer.

How can we improve the structure so it doesn't break the EF code first migrations? Or cause any other issues?

Should we just have a unique ASP.net project for each customer that references the `MyApp.Core`? And should we reference those via a nuget package? Or something else like a git sub module?

Any suggestions on the organization of the custom implementations of this type of structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be an IsA (Is-a, is a) database structure that can be created from your code-first model using the TPC method mentioned here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

You might create an abstraction such as ICustomer, or CustomerBase which contains a reference to a table containing the implementations of your application (is that Product?).

You might also transform your Customer class into a base class, and other classes with additional fields would inherit from it.

In either event, the article deals with bringing code first into a database model that can handle this kind of thing. You may also want to take a look at multi-tenant architecture, just to say you've done your homework. That's here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: Then would you keep the DbContext in the Core? Or in a customer implementation

Comment: In the cases mentioned in the first article, it would remain in the core, because you only have 1 database. It's very similar, at that point(your scope may expand) to having a single business with multiple types of customers. You should consider the 3 different techniques in the article.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of the techniques, I am trying to find a better way. We are required to have multiple databases per customer, so that isn't an issue.